# Spring validation of List is not empty

Tags: java, spring, list, validation, spring-mvc

I cann't understand the reason of problem. I have **List** in my model and I want to validate it, using Spring and interface **Validator**

```
public class OperationList {
   private List<String> operations;
}
```

in index.jsp

```
<sf:form method="post" commandName="operationsList" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/operation">
<p>
    <sf:checkboxes   element="li" path="operations" items="${list}" ></sf:checkboxes>
    <sf:errors path="operations" cssStyle="color: #ff0000"></sf:errors>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
```

in controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/operation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processOperation( @ModelAttribute @Valid OperationList opList, HttpSession session,
        BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView mav =new ModelAndView();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        mav.setViewName("index");
    } else {
        session.setAttribute("operations", opList);
        mav.setViewName("switchfile");
    }
    return mav;
}
```

validator:

```
@Component
public class OperationValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    return OperationList.class.equals(arg0);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors err) {
    OperationList opearationList = (OperationList) obj;

    List<String> opers = opearationList.getOperations();
    if(opers==null || opers.isEmpty()){
        err.rejectValue("operations", "operationlist.oplist.empty");
    }
}
```

When I send post request (/operation) with empty OperationList I get error instead index.jsp with error string.

```
the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Can anybody explain the reason of this troubles? And in tcp/ip monitor i see record "_operations=on"
When I mark check boxes and OperationList  is not empty everything works fine. And one funny thing. In my application I have enother validator for file uploading. So it works fine.
I use hibernate-validator v.5.1.3; Spring v.4.1.6. server - tomcat 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem.
The **BindingResult** result parameter always directly after the parameter with the **@Value** annotation